# grep in txt file or files without extension, require multiple strings to be present in the file

Tags: grep

I want to recursively search a directory for files with either a .txt extension or no extension which has 2 strings that im searching for present at the same time. How can I manage that?

For example there are 5 files somewhere inside this directory that contain "string 1", "string 2" and "string 3" inside them. 2 of them are .pdf and .html which I am not interested in. Remaining 3 are .txt files and/or have no extension. I would like to get the paths of those which contain all the strings inside them and have the .txt extension or no extensions at all.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output

Comment: Good idea, I edited and provided an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for the modified question:

```
find directory -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o ! -name '*.*' \) \
    -exec grep -q -F -e 'string 1' {} \; \
    -exec grep -q -F -e 'string 2' {} \; \
    -exec grep -q -F -e 'string 3' {} \; \
    -print
```

This searches the directory called `directory` recursively for regular files with a `.txt` filename suffix, and for regular files with no dot in their names.  When such a file is found, `grep` is use in a way similar to what I previously described (see below) to figure out whether all three strings are present in the file.

If the strings are found, then the pathname of the file is printed.

Alternatively, using the code from my first installment of this anwer (from below):

```
find directory -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o ! -name '*.*' \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if  grep -q -F -e "string 1" "$pathname" &&
            grep -q -F -e "string 2" "$pathname" &&
            grep -q -F -e "string 3" "$pathname"
        then
            printf "All were found in \"%s\"\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Old answer from before the modification to the question:

The name of the file is of no consequence as Unix does not infer a file type from the file name.

To test whether a string is present in some file called `file`, one may do

```
if grep -q -F -e 'some string' file; then
    echo 'The string is present'
else
    echo 'The string is not present'
fi
```

The options used with `grep` here are

- `-q`:  This makes `grep` quiet, and it also makes it terminate as soon as the pattern matches.  Instead of extracting the line(s) where the pattern matches, it exits with an exit status reflecting whether a match was found or not.  This exit status is what I'm using in the `if` statement above.
- `-F`: This makes `grep` treat the pattern as a string rather than a regular expression.  This makes it possible to test whether strings like `a * [in the] sky` occurs in a text, without having to escape the special characters in it.
- `-e`: This makes `grep` treat the next argument as the pattern to use for matching with.  This makes it possible to use a pattern starting with `-` without `grep` thinking it's a command line option.

To test several strings, add further `grep` tests like this:

```bsh
if  grep -q -F -e 'string 1' file &&
    grep -q -F -e 'string 2' file &&
    grep -q -F -e 'string 3' file
then
    echo 'All three string were found in the file'
else
    echo 'One or more string was not found in the file'
fi
```

Assuming one is using a shell that has named arrays (such as `bash`), one could also store the strings in an array and do a loop like so:

```bsh
strings=( 'string 1' 'string 2' 'string 3' )

found=true
for string in "${strings[@]}"; do
    if ! grep -q -F -e "$string" file; then
        found=false
        break
    fi
done

if "$found"; then
    echo 'All strings were found'
else
    echo 'Not all strings were found'
fi
```

This iterates over the strings, and if one of them is *not* found (note the `!` which negates the result of the `grep` test), then the variable `found` is set to `false` and the loop is exited (we don't need to test further strings).

We then test whether `$found` is `true` or `false` and act on the result of that test.

The above shell code rewritten for `/bin/sh` (without named arrays):

```bsh
set -- 'string 1' 'string 2' 'string 3'

found=true
for string do
    if ! grep -q -F -e "$string" file; then
        found=false
        break
    fi
done

if "$found"; then
    echo 'All strings were found'
else
    echo 'Not all strings were found'
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, though I didnt mean a single file in the question. I reworded it to be more specific.

Comment: @upperdim See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for multiple strings is a job for awk, not for grep:

```
find directory -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o ! -name '*.*' \) \
    -exec awk '
              index($0,"string 1"){x=1}
              index($0,"string 2"){y=1}
              index($0,"string 3"){z=1}
              x && y && z { f=1; exit }
              END { exit !f }
              ' {} \; \
    -print
```

Note that in the above awk is only called once per input file instead of once per string per input file. It's also trivial to write a script to find any number of strings instead of hard-coding them a line at a time and still just call awk once per file, e.g.:

```
find directory -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o ! -name '*.*' \) \
    -exec awk '
              BEGIN {
                  totReqd = split("string 1 \
                                   string 2 \
                                   string 3", strings, /[[:space:]]+\n[[:space:]]+/)
              }
              {
                  for (idx in strings) {
                      if ( index($0,strings[idx]) ) {
                          totFound++
                          delete strings[idx]
                      }
                  }
              }
              totFound == totReqd { f=1; exit }
              END { exit !f }
              ' {} \; \
    -print
```

Both of the above are untested but should be close if not exactly correct. They could further be easily modified to operate on multiple files at a time.

Answer (score -2):

Edited bellow for updated question
you can grep 2 patterns using -e option.  Files that you are looking into doesn't need to have extension, just use wildcard so you your statement would look something like this

```
grep -e "word1" -e "word 2"  /your/folder/*
```

or this way for even 3 strings in files that consist word "txt"

```
 grep 'word1\|word2\|word3'  /your/folder/*txt*
```

Try it to see what you get

if you would like to find both strings in the same line you can just do

```
grep "word 1"  /your/folder/* | grep "word 2"
```

That will pipe results for first grep to another with different string.
or do the following

```
grep -e 'word1.*word2\|word2.*word1'  /your/folder/*
```

so it would look for word1 first and word2 second or vice versa

Comment: That's useful and solves one of my problems I think, thanks

Comment: This appears to search for any single one of the strings. Not all three together. It would also try to match strings in a file called `txt.html`.